# Imputing missing observations of zip code level data

Tags: missing-data, spatial, data-imputation, geostatistics, synthetic-data

I am looking for a sufficient imputation method for missing observations in my zip code level data, using R.

I have a **random** sample consisting of households which live in different zip codes within one city. My goal is to use this sample to synthesize an "artificial" census for this city. Unfortunately, the households in the sample do not cover all the zip codes of the city. Therefore, if I would synthesize from this incomplete sample, the "artificial" census would also not cover those missing zip codes.

The sample data has this structure:

```
ID Income Rent hh-Members ... Zip code
1   4367  453     3              12
2   4372  563     1              23
...
```

I would therefore like to impute those zip codes by adding "artificial households" to my sample before I synthesize the census data from it. *The assumption is, that households living in neighboring zip codes are more similar to each other than non-neighboring ones.*

Is there any common way to solve this problem?

I am hoping that there might be a package for this issue.

Comment: This is a large and complex task. I have never heard of someone trying to do this and there is unlikely to be an available procedure. You could describe the problem you want to solve with the resulting data set.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! My aim is to create a complete artificial census dataset for a given city, including observations from all available zip codes.

Comment: Why do you want this artificial census? Is each household or each person a separate item or are these aggregated into groups denoted census tracts?

Comment: It's my thesis task to create this census, and the procedure has been discussed with my advisor. Each household is one observation. I was wondering: I can't be the only one who needs to tackle missing observations for geographical units. I hoped there would be a standard procedure for this in geostatistics or in a similar discipline. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This sounds to me more like a topic in simulation than imputation. Imputation usually deals with relatively small numbers of imputed values compared with the number of observed values. It has been used this way in censuses, surveys, and clinical trials, all where a modest proportion of observations are missing.